# Li tag with different rows

Tags: html, css

I have multiple li elements, but I want to follow a format of the following li's per row (centrally aligned):

```
3
4
3
3
3 etc...
```

I previously set this up within a flexbox, but could'nt work out how to do this. So I have used display:inline-block.

```css
.meet-team li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.meet-team li:nth-of-type(4),
.meet-team li:nth-of-type(9) {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<ul class="meet-team">
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: after `etc` they will always remain 3 per row

Comment: Yes 3 per row will follow

Comment: Your examples are not clear. I created a snippet for you. Can you show an image of expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try flexbox and simply use a different `flex-basis` (or width) for the second row:

```css
ul {
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.meet-team li {
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-basis: 33%;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align:center;
}

.meet-team li:nth-of-type(4),
.meet-team li:nth-of-type(5),
.meet-team li:nth-of-type(6),
.meet-team li:nth-of-type(7) {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="meet-team">
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
</ul>
```